# dismissで閉じて再度ページ遷移するとクラッシュする

Tags: swift, xcode

なぜか1度閉じてもう１度開くとクラッシュします。
コンソールにエラーは出ません
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)

exception break point 追加してますが表示されません

遷移元

```swift
import UIKit
class AbcViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    // ScrollScreenの高さ
    var scrollScreenHeight:CGFloat!
    // ScrollScreenの幅
    var scrollScreenWidth:CGFloat!

    var screenSize:CGRect!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        // ページスクロールとするためにページ幅を合わせる
        scrollScreenWidth = screenSize.width
        scrollScreenHeight = screenSize.height

        setupFirebase()
    }

    func setupFirebase() {

        // 自作セルをテーブルビューに登録する
        let communityXib = UINib(nibName: "CommunityTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))

        // 描画開始の x,y 位置
        let px:CGFloat = 0.0
        var py:CGFloat = 0.0

        let communityView = communityXib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        communityView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            print("あああ")
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AbcViewController.btnClick(sender:forEvent:)))

        communityView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(communityView)

        // 描画開始設定
        var viewFrame:CGRect = communityView.frame
        viewFrame.size.width = self.scrollScreenWidth
        viewFrame.size.height = self.scrollScreenHeight
        viewFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: px, y: py)
        communityView.frame = viewFrame
        // 次の描画位置設定
        py += (self.screenSize.height)

        // スクロール範囲の設定
        let nHeight:CGFloat = self.scrollScreenHeight * CGFloat(1)
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollScreenWidth, height: nHeight)
    }

    @objc func btnClick(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        print("ムカつく")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTest", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

遷移先

```swift
import UIKit

class DefViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func closePage(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: 残念ながら、あなたがご質問に掲載のコードだけ取り出してもご説明の事象を再現することはできませんでした。質問用にコードを簡略化したのであれば、簡略化のために削られた部分に原因があるのかもしれませんし、Storyboardなどコード以外の部分に何らかの問題があるのかもしれません。とりあえず「クラッシュ」するのであれば、デバッグコンソールになんらかのメッセージが表示されると思うので、そのメッセージを(あるいは関係ありそうな他の情報も)ご質問に追記してください。ご自身の質問は「編集」から修正を行うことができるはずです。

Comment: エラーはThread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)です

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記のコードに変更して、解決しました

```
@objc func btnClick(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("ムカつく")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTest", sender: nil)
}

let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.btnClick(_:)))
```